# Why is my car tramlining(pulling/veering when I hit road imperfections)?

Tags: suspension, steering

So twice this has happened, and the first time it was much more violent. So far I have replace the upper control arm "inner" bushings on the right side but today it happened again, but not as bad, and it may just be because I wasn't going nearly as fast. The power steering fluid is full. I replaced my rack with a used one about 6 months ago. It was in good condition but the mechanic I had helping me complained about how he couldn't do it, wanted to buy it, so a week later I walk in and within an hour or so I get the last line hooked up. What do you know while I'm under the car he dumps brake fluid in it and fills it up. It's either the left side bushings, upper ball joints, outer tie rods or cv joints.. because recently and most likely unrelated, when I make a U-Turn or very sharp turn i hear a ticking like something is in a bind. I've had the car for seven years and it's lowered but I've never had any issues. A couple months ago I found that my struts weren't even hand tight as well.

Comment: Do you have aftermarket low-profile wheels?

Comment: Yeah with lowering springs and the upper control arms have a camber adjustment. Four allen nuts on each side.

Comment: I ask because this happens when you have low-profile tyres: they don't flex like high profile tyres, so any time you hit a bump or groove in the road, all that force gets transferred up the steering rack, instead of being absorbed by the tyre. Usually this happens round about the 50 profile mark and gets worse the lower you go. It's not your only problem, but it contributes to it. Softer springs may help.

Comment: I think they are 205/40R17. I sit about 3 inches from the ground at the highest point.

Comment: Those will do it. But as I said: it's probably not your only problem. It just amplifies it.

Comment: Well could I rule out the steering column and power steering pump, maybe even the cv axle?

Comment: Take it somewhere else and have it looked at. The ticking you talked about could be a CV.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent bushing wear and what parts besides the suspension uses bushings?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15234/how-do-i-prevent-bushing-wear-and-what-parts-besides-the-suspension-uses-bushing)

Comment: Well I'm doing the CV axles because the left side is ticking when I turn, the bearings in case they are seizing up and the front brake calipers in case they are not releasing, then eventually the rotors as I've heard the grooves in the new calipers actually help to dissipate heat.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQktkhPj3yg

Comment: I am voting to keep this question open because the question marked as having already answered this question **has no answers**.

Comment: It was definitely the brake calipers sticking. I ended up replacing the whole front brake assembly and CV axles, but WD40 made it stop. My brake pads were nearly gone.

Answer (score 8):

What you are describing is called bump steer.

This is caused by a toe change when the suspension travels vertically.

Common Causes include

- Incorrect tie rod height or lenght
- steering rack that is not mounted parallel to the datum plane.
- bent steering parts
- structural damage to the vehicle

I'd start by checking the mounting of the steering rack since it was recently replaced. Make sure it's level and make sure the tie rod ends are not bent.